# Using trimmomatic on multiple Illumina paired-end read files

Tags: for-loop, bioinformatics

I would like use trimmomatic http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic to remove known adapter sequences from paired-end Illumina transcriptome data.

I am able to to run the program for a single set of paired reads. However, I would really like to run a command that will function on multiple paired reads in a given directory.

The files in my directory are under the following format

run number_unique identifier_fwd or rev (where 1=fwd and 2=rev).fastq.gz

```
1_EupS0510_1.fastq.gz
1_EupS0510_2.fastq.gz
1_EupS0675_1.fastq.gz
1_EupS0675_2.fastq.gz
1_EupM0685_1.fastq.gz
1_EupM0685_2.fastq.gz
1_Ela319_1.fastq.gz
1_Ela319_2.fastq.gz
1_EupAx10439_1.fastq.gz
1_EupAx10439_2.fastq.gz
1_EupTT12454_1.fastq.gz
1_EupTT12454_2.fastq.gz
2_EupS0510_1.fastq.gz
2_EupS0510_2.fastq.gz
2_EupS0675_1.fastq.gz
2_EupS0675_2.fastq.gz
2_EupM0685_1.fastq.gz
2_EupM0685_2.fastq.gz
2_Ela319_1.fastq.gz
2_Ela319_2.fastq.gz
2_EupAx10439_1.fastq.gz
2_EupAx10439_2.fastq.gz
2_EupTT12454_1.fastq.gz
2_EupTT12454_2.fastq.gz
```

To run trimmomatic for the paired reads corresponding to 1_EupS0510_1.fastq.gz and 1_EupS0510_2.fastq.gz, the following command works:

```
java -jar /local/software/trimmomatic/0.32/trimmomatic-0.32.jar PE -phred33 1_SiMM0510_1.fastq.gz 1_SiMM0510_2.fastq.gz  paired.output_1_SiMM0510_1.fastq.gz unpaired.output_1_SiMM0510_1.fastq.gz paired.output_1_SiMM0510_2.fastq.gz unpaired.output_1_SiMM0510_2.fastq.gz  ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeqAdapters.fst:2:30:10
```

This is simply following the framework provided by trimmomatic

```
java -jar <path to trimmomatic.jar> PE [-phred33 | -phred64] <input 1> <input 2> <paired output 1> <unpaired output 1> <paired output 2> <unpaired output 2> <step 1>
```

I do not know how to create a loop function that can repeat the command for all the files in a given directory whilst maintaing the link between paired end reads.

If anyone would have any suggestions it would be really helpful

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f1 in *_1.fastq.gz
do
    f2=${f1%%_1.fastq.gz}"_2.fastq.gz"
    java -jar ...stuff... $f1 $f2 ...moreFiles...
done
```

You might also just strip off _1.fastq.gz and use that as a base name for everything else, as I did above for `f2`.